# PHP - Call echo script outside

Tags: php, javascript, html, tags, call

I've got a real problem, I want to make an alert using PHP to call JavaScript, but my PHP is inside a textarea, is there anyway to echo out the script outside the textarea without moving the PHP code?

```
<textarea>
<?php
echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Hello!')</script>"
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: What is your real intent?

Comment: Where do you need to echo it from? You can use short tags if they are enabled and echo anywhere (`<?= $script ?>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. Once you're inside a `<textarea>`, **ANY** text, including html tags, will be considered part of the textarea's "to be edited text", up until the first `</textarea>`. You will have to output your script tag outside of the textarea, which means moving your PHP code.

Comment: So it's impossible or what?

Comment: Can't I use some kind of include files or AJAX?

Comment: pretty much. you'll have to output the script tag somewhere else. a `<script>` block is NOT valid inside a textarea, as anything other than "plain text".

Comment: But is there anyway I could call a function from the textarea and run it outside or something...?

Comment: no. because you CAN NOT execute javascript within the textarea. you can run whatever PHP you want inside the textarea, but any output of the PHP will become editable text.

Comment: But can I change the content of an element with PHP do?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo "<script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello!');</script>"
?>

<textarea></textarea>
```

This function and the alert you can't write inside the textarea